# Finding for string in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is basically, I will be trying to get data from a table called, 'rank' and it will have data formatted like, "1,2,3,4,5" etc to grant permissions. So Basically I am trying to make it an array and find if one number is there in the array. Basically making it an array is not working. How would I get this done? Here is my code below:

```
<?php
    function rankCheck($rank) {
        $ranks = "1,2,3,4,5";
        print_r($uRanks = array($ranks));
        if(in_array($rank, $uRanks)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(rankCheck(5) == true) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "What?"; }
?>
```

This code returns false, while it should return true. This is just a basic algorithm.

The print_r Display:

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,5 )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. I used the explode function instead like this:

```
<?php
    function rankCheck($rank) {
        $ranks = "1,2,3,4,5";
        print_r($uRanks = explode(',', $ranks));
        if(in_array($rank, $uRanks)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(rankCheck(5) == true) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "What?"; }
?>
```

Comment: It is better to accept any of the answers posted above instead of writing your own one here.

Answer (score 4):

If you know for sure your delimiter is a comma, try this:

```
$ranks = explode(',',$rank);
```

where $rank is your string.

Answer (score 3):

That's simple, you [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) the `$ranks` variable by comma `,`:

```
$ranks = "1,2,3,4,5";
$uRanks = explode(',',$ranks);
//$uRanks would now be array(1,2,3,4,5);
if(in_array($rank, $uRanks)) {
//..rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You should:

```
 $uRanks = explode(',', $ranks);
```

instead of:

```
$uRanks = array($ranks);
```

to make this as array.